# Problem when Installing Redmine

Tags: redmine

I'm trying to install Redmine and was followed steps as mentioned on page http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall, but I get an error in the step-8, the message was:

```
D:\Permana\Develop\Ruby\redmine-1.1.2>ruby script/server webrick -e production
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 2.3.5 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
D:/Permana/Develop/Ruby/redmine-1.1.2/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:119:in `requirement': undefined local variable or method `version_requirements' for #<Rails::GemDependency:0x33ca6f8> (NameError)
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:254:in `activate'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1204:in `gem'
        from D:/Permana/Develop/Ruby/redmine-1.1.2/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:73:in `add_load_paths'
        from D:/Permana/Develop/Ruby/redmine-1.1.2/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:301:in `add_gem_load_paths'
        from D:/Permana/Develop/Ruby/redmine-1.1.2/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:301:in `each'
        from D:/Permana/Develop/Ruby/redmine-1.1.2/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:301:in `add_gem_load_paths'
        from D:/Permana/Develop/Ruby/redmine-1.1.2/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:132:in `process'
        from D:/Permana/Develop/Ruby/redmine-1.1.2/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
        from D:/Permana/Develop/Ruby/redmine-1.1.2/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
        from D:/Permana/Develop/Ruby/redmine-1.1.2/config/environment.rb:20
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in`gem_original_require'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in`require'
        from D:/Permana/Develop/Ruby/redmine-1.1.2/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
        from D:/Permana/Develop/Ruby/redmine-1.1.2/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
        from D:/Permana/Develop/Ruby/redmine-1.1.2/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
        from D:/Permana/Develop/Ruby/redmine-1.1.2/vendor/rails/railties/lib/commands/server.rb:84
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in`gem_original_require'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in`require'
        from script/server:3

D:\Permana\Develop\Ruby\redmine-1.1.2>
```

I try to open http://localhost:3000/ and returns 404.

I know nothing about Ruby on Rails but I'm good at PHP. I really interested in Redmine after trying the demo and plan to Integrate it with SVN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is almost definitely your version of Ruby Gems. [Redmine has problems with version 1.5+ of gems](http://www.redmine.org/issues/7516).

The output of `gem -v` on your system will confirm it - if it's >= 1.5.0 you'd be best installing an older version instead (until they release Redmine 1.2, according to that bug report).

Comment: Thanks for the respon simon. It solve my problem. However, there are another problem. How can I update % done ? I cannot found where should I update the % done value. Also, when my friend try to access the redmine from another computer via LAN. Redmine runs very slow. But it runs very fast from localhost (of course)